# How do I make all current and future files in a directory readable by a certain group/user?

Tags: permissions, osx, acl

I have a "Drop Box" directory for students to submit assignments.  Its permissions are set to "drwx-wx---" where all of the students belong to the group.  This lets them write to but not read from the folder.  I would like to set up ACLs so user cs63 (an account used by the teaching staff) can read all files.  I tried doing:

```
chmod +a "user:cs63 allow read,file_inherit,directory_inherit" Top
```

on the top-level directory in which all of the Drop Box directories appear.  When I look at the attributes with "ls -lde", I see:

```
user:cs63 allow list,file_inherit,directory_inherit
```

I assume that "read" was changed to "list" because "read" isn't applicable to directories, but how do I specify that I want cs63 to be able to read, not just list, all of the files?

Also, once I set the right ACL, will it apply to files that have already been submitted or only future ones?

I connect to the server via ssh, so I need to do all of this at the command line.

EDIT:

I tried @mindc's suggestion of:

```
chmod -R +a "user:cs63 allow read,file_inherit,directory_inherit" Top
```

It worked for most files, but not for a subdirectory whose permissions were:

```
drwx---rwx+ student cs63sp12
```

where user cs63 is a member of cs63sp12.  When I do "ls -le" on the subdirectory, I get:

```
0: user:cs63 allow list,file_inherit,directory_inherit
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the `-R` switch, like this:

```
chmod -R +a "user:cs63 allow read,file_inherit,directory_inherit" Top
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  That seemed to do it.  Could you give me a little explanation to go along with it, and let me know if it would work with future files added to the directories or if I'd have to put it in a cron job?

Comment: Actually, it didn't quite work.  See edit.